# How to get sed to include a double \\ that's included in a variable

Tags: sed

I'm writing a script in bash that performs a simple transform of a file we'll call storage.config.

Parameters are passed from our automation system (VCAC\AppD) to our action script, which performs the transform using sed.

To keep things simple, I'll use the following example

**storage.config - To be transformed**

```
url=jdbc:sqlserver://@myDB
```

**Transform Script**

```
myDB='serverxyz\\instance'

sed -i -e "s,@myDB,$myDB,g" storage.config
```

I would expect the resulting storage.config to look like this;

```
url=jdbc:sqlserver://serverxyz\\instance
```

However, it looks like this instead;

```
url=jdbc:sqlserver://serverxyz\instance
```

I've read through the answers on this site, as well as others. And have found a lot of useful information on how to include variable, single vs. double quotes, but nothing on how to retain a double \ in a variable. I'd like to get sed to interpret correctly, rather than type something like;

```
myDB='serverxyz\\\\instance'
```

This value will be entered by Solutions Engineers, who might enter improperly as they don't recognize it as a valid SQL instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` **is** interpreting it correctly.

You are sticking `\\` in the replacement as a literal string.

`sed` doesn't know it was a variable from somewhere else and not just typed out manually.

Escaping it **is** the answer.

You can do it at expansion time with `${myDB//\\/\\\\}` if you want though.

Additionally, as @abesto quite correctly indicated in his answer, you are loosing the doubled slash before `sed` even sees it. Use single quotes in your assignment to preserve it.

```
myDB='server\\instance'
```

Comment: You're Amazing!

    myDB='serverxyz\\instance'

    sed -i -e "s,@myDB,${myDB//\\/\\\\},g" storage.config

Did the trick!! 1st post ever, and everyone nailed it within 18 minutes!

Answer (score 1):

The double `\` doesn't even get as far as sed. Your shell sees `\\`, and reads it as "oh, you want a `\`, because you escaped it". You can try it out like this:

```
myDB="serverxyz\\instance"
echo "$myDB"
# output: serverxyz\instance
```

Comment: As long as we are talking about proper quoting/etc. you should probably quote the expansion of `"$myDB"`.

Comment: Etan\Abesto - Thanks for your responses\comments.

That example was a desperation attempt. I've since changed it back to a single quote. echo displays it correct, but the results in my transform script is identical. I'll update my example above to avoid further confusion.

Comment: Right. In that case the double quotes really do get to sed; see Etan's answer

Answer (score 0):

So in conclusion (Thanks to all that responded. Special thanks to @Etan);

```
myDB='serverxyz\\instance'

sed -i -e "s,@myDB,${myDB//\\/\\\\},g" storage.config
```

The above code results in the proper translation\transform of my storage.config file. The resulting storage.config is as follows;

```
url=jdbc:sqlserver://serverxyz\\instance
```